# Count graphs on $n$ vertices with at least one $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ sized clique

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

I am lookin for any reasonable formula for the number of graphs on $n$ vertices which have at least one $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$-clique.

The naive attempt is to try to count all possible cliques and then fill in the rest of the graph - but this is overcounting by a lot. I also tried OEIS and it did not help me much.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the nodes labeled or unlabeled?

Comment: @templatetypedef On a fixed set of vertices.

Comment: Can you show your attempt thus far and where you're overcounting things?